# Call a custom phtml file to particular section Magento ver 1.6 to 1.9

Tags: module, layout, magento-1, custom

I created a custom module (For Magento ver 1.6 to ver 1.9 ) in which i show custom phtml file and insert custom js and css as well, I included it to two pages only with particular section i.e footer section and right sidebar ( if enabled ).

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">

  <reference name="bottom.container">
              <block type="custommodule/bottomwidgethome" name="custommodule_bottomwidgethome" template="custommodule/bottomwidgethome.phtml" />
  </reference>

  <reference name="head">
      <action method="addItem">
          <type>skin_js</type>
          <name>custommodule/js/hb_popupforms.js</name>
          <params>defer</params>
      </action>
</reference>
 ....................

</cms_index_index>
```

I tried it in Magento ver **1.6.x to ver 1.9.x**

All my template will go to **base/default** folder structure so **that it will be available for all.**

Issue: I tried and it works fine, unfortunately in one of the Magento theme there was no `bottom.container` in `/var/www/html/newthme19/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml`

I am assuming

```
1) app/design/frontend/{CUSTOM-PACKAGE}/{MY-THEME}

2) app/design/frontend/{CUSTOM-PACKAGE}/{DEFAULT}

3) app/design/frontend/base/{DEFAULT}
```

that my custom template will be called at last from base/default

This is the structure block to which I am referring and any other module can also refer the same, this block by default is present in base/default.

```
   <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
       <label>Page Footer</label>
       <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
</block>
```

Comment: you can not expect an extension to work in every 3rd party theme, as one can create a whole new theme without following container/reference name from base/default theme. To make it work you have to customize layout as per the theme

Comment: So by default there should be a `bottom.container` in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml` are you referring to one of Magento's default themes or, as @Piyush already mentioned, a custom/third party theme?

Comment: I agree with @Piyush sir , but i am asuming that no one deletes `bottom.container` from base/default , and if it is there than my phtml must be called? am I wrong in my assumption sir

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan it depends on if  `base/default` is parent theme of that theme or not, you can check your theme's `layout.phtml` (1-column, 3-columns, etc) files  for the `bottom.container` block, if it is not there you have to use an alternative.

Comment: @Piyush sir i updated the question ( question bottom section )

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan Yes it will, but if your theme has overridden structural blocks it will not use base theme's block, base theme's layout will be used only if that particular template files not found in current/active theme

Comment: sir by particular template file means  my Custom template file